# Send the location to the server every n minutes in the background in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i want to sent the location to the server when the app is background, i tried with many way but can't get the solution

I tried with the timer function using the timer and using function

```
        self.bgtimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:60, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.bgtimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(self.bgtimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        RunLoop.current.run()
```

but i when i stop the timer when the app becomes active

```
     if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
         RunLoop.current.cancelPerformSelectors(withTarget: self.bgtimer)
        timer.invalidate()

    }
```

but the app not function properly collection view and back function everything is not working properly

Comment: Don't use a timer, event if you get it work it will drain the battery. Just register for location change and sent the location to the server once it changes. This is also in the Apple documentation.

Comment: Thank you
 i tried with this code
       func createRegion(location:CLLocation?) {

    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
            let regionRadius = 50.0

Comment: let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: coordinate.latitude,
                longitude: coordinate.longitude),
                                          radius: regionRadius,
                                          identifier: "aabb")

            region.notifyOnExit = true
            region.notifyOnEntry = true
            self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
            self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: region)

Comment: but it is not calling the func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
when the cross the region

Comment: can you please post your answer for monitoring the changes of the distance when the app is in background

Comment: You are using geofencing, it will only trigger once you enter/leave that region. Use  the [`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati) for battery friendly location changes.

Comment: startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() i added in the applicationdidenterbackround function but i is calling only one time when i move to various place also it is not call the func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

Comment: can you please give the code which i need to run in the applicationDidEnterBackground function to send the location to the server as changes in the location or certain meters to fix, when the user cross the meter mentioned, has to send the coordinates to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In DidBackground:

1. stop normalTimer.
2. start New backgroundTaskTimer

> In WillForeground:

1. stop backgroundTaskTimer.
2. start normalTimer

Find below sample code:

> In Appdelegate:
>
> Declaration:

```
  var backgroundUpdateTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier!

  var backgroundTaskTimer:Timer! = Timer()
```

> Implementation:

```
func doBackgroundTask() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        self.beginBackgroundTask()

        if self.backgroundTaskTimer != nil {
            self.backgroundTaskTimer.invalidate()
            self.backgroundTaskTimer = nil
        }

        //Making the app to run in background forever by calling the API
        self.backgroundTaskTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startTracking), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(self.backgroundTaskTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        RunLoop.current.run()

        // End the background task.
        self.endBackgroundTask()

    }
}

func beginBackgroundTask() {
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "Track trip", expirationHandler: {
        self.endBackgroundTask()
    })
}

func endBackgroundTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundUpdateTask)
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

> In ApplicationDidEnterBackground:

```
 func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    //Start the background fetch
     self.doBackgroundTask()
 }
```

> In ApplicationWillEnterForeground:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if self.backgroundTaskTimer != nil {
        self.backgroundTaskTimer.invalidate()
        self.backgroundTaskTimer = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: ya done, I found that when the device is in lock state and the app is in background mode, it is running for some minutes but after that the timer got stopped in some times, is there any solution for this to run the background process for 24/7 ?

Comment: In target - capability- enable background fetch

Comment: ya done, I found that when the device is in lock state and the app is in background mode, it is running for some minutes but after that the timer got stopped in some times, is there any solution for this to run the background process for 24/7 ?

background fetch is already enabled, it happen some times only

Comment: That is not possible in iOS. Apple will not allow for that

Comment: how much time longer timer will run in the background

Comment: Its based on background apps and application suspend state